# How to SUMIF (from Google Sheets) using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Sheets has this function called SUMIF(), which I'm using inside an IF statement:

```
=IF(SUMIF(January!$F$6:$F,$B2,January!$G$6:$G)=0,"",SUMIF(January!$F$6:$F,$B2,January!$G$6:$G))
```

The IF is just to show an empty cell in case the value = `0`

**January!$F$6:$F** is a column with names

**$B2** is the cell with the name to compare against `January!$F$6:$F`

**January!$G$6:$G** is a column with numerical values

I'm using this function in many places, and each time I have to update a value is quite painful.

So I would to create my own function using the *script editor*, parsing the three values mentioned above:

```
=myOwnFunction(columnNames,columnValues,names)
```

**Edited**

There's [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796526/google-apps-script-alternative-to-sumif) asking a similar question, but he is working on a Macro, so when I tried to apply the same rules such as `setValue` I get a restriction error.

Can I get some help please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a link the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates) where you find step by step tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was already [discussed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796526/google-apps-script-alternative-to-sumif).

Now I can suggest something similar:

```
function myOwnFunction(columnNames, columnValues, names) {
  var res = 0;
  for (var i in columnNames) {
    if (columnNames[i][0] == names) res += columnValues[i][0];
  }
  if (res == 0) res = '';
  return res;
}
```

Note, I've used your own function name. But traditionally custom function names are uppercase, such as MY_OWN_FUNCTION.